# str_replace function replace placeholders

Tags: php

I've got the following string which has been loaded from a database into $message.

`Hi,\n\nYou have a new voicemail message from ${VM_CIDNAME} (${VM_CIDNUM}), on ${VM_DATE}.\n\nThank you for using 123 Solutions.`

I'm trying to str_replace the placeholders in that string with real data, but since PHP is interpreting ${VM_CIDNAME}, it isn't performing a replacement.

`$message = str_replace("${VM_CIDNUM}", $CallerID , $message);`

How can I replace the placeholders?

Note: Changing the format of the placeholders is not an option as it's hard coded into third party software which I cannot change.

I also need to str_replace the "\n" characters with newlines.

Many thanks

Comment: Try once without `$` sign. I think its considering it as a variable. so you maybe need to str_replace to set $callerId and then str_replace('$', '', text)

Comment: if you wants to use str_replace then remove the $ sign from the string because $ sign is reserved by php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use single quotes`(')`

```
$message = str_replace('${VM_CIDNUM}', $CallerID , $message);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 2):

Try using single quote(')

```
$message = str_replace('${VM_CIDNUM}', $CallerID , $message);
```

and to replace "\n" use nl2br() PHP function as

```
$message = nl2br($message);
```

Comment: ln2br() seems to replace real new lines with BRs, but in my case, it isn't a new line but the text "\n". IE the backslash character followed by an 'n'.

Comment: I resolved the \n issue by doing this
`$message = str_replace('\n', "\n" , $message);`

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
/* SET string variables before set $message */

$VM_CIDNAME = $CallerNAME; /* Your CallerNAME variable */
$VM_CIDNUM = $CallerID; /* Your CallerID variable */
$VM_DATE = $CallerDATE; /* Your CallerDATE variable */

/* then */
 $message = "Hi,\n\nYou have a new voicemail message from ${VM_CIDNAME} (${VM_CIDNUM}), on ${VM_DATE}.\n\nThank you for using 123 Solutions.";
 $message = nl2br($message);
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
$VM_CIDNAME = 'John';
$VM_CIDNUM = '1234';
$VM_DATE = '2017-01-01';
$dbRes = $mailboxinfo['emailbody'];
$ev = '$message = "' . $dbRes . '";';
eval($ev);
$message = nl2br($message);
```

without nothing to replace

Comment: Note, I am not setting $message in that way. It is coming from a database so is being set like this `$mailboxinfo = $statement->fetch();  $message = $mailboxinfo['emailbody'];`